# Specify log level in Jboss AS 7.1

Tags: java, logging, jboss

I am using JBoss AS 7.1 . I want to somehow specify  that  only  ERROR  gets printed on the console .

Comment: Look for your log4j.xml file and modify it appropriately.

Comment: I don't have log4j.xml file

Comment: Documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Logging+Configuration

Answer (score 1):

Open `standalone.xml`

Go to

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.0">
   <console-handler name="CONSOLE" autoflush="true">
       <level name="DEBUG"/>
```

Change level to `ERROR` from `DEBUG`